# Are there any rate limit on google end for cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We have a prod app that uses firestore and recently discovered an issue led us to believe 20% of user post release are having issue subscribing to firestore (probably because all end users are refreshing/reconnecting at the same time)

My question is:

1. How do we prove this is the theory?  Working with our SRE seems like there is no data or log for firestore connectivity at all.  We are hoping there is log/stats of any kind.
2. Are there rate limiting on google's end for firestore?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "having issues subscribing to firestore"?  What are you observing?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson !   TLDR - we had a bad logic that ddos our own service essentially, and base on code base it would only happen if user can't establish firestore subscription, so on failure it does "something" that hit our own service and try re-establish firestore subscription again... over and over.   So our guess is that during a software release, user base had to reconnect and a large number of them coudln't re-establish connection back to firestore.   So we are hoping to find out more about what exactly happened.